# How to call API from view using jQuery and AJAX in an ASP.NET Core MVC project?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created an ASP.NET MVC project to perform CRUD operations from list instead of using database, using `HomeController` and an API controller. Now I want to edit that project such a way that I want to call API functions directly from my view which is an HTML page.

The control is passing from view to home controller then to API controller. I want a direct connection between view and API using jQuery and AJAX.

What all further details should I specify with the question?

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#login').click(function () {
                     var x = $('#email1').val()
                     var y = $('#pswd').val()
 
                     $.ajax({
                         type: "GET",
                         url: "https://localhost:44347/api/Values/Login/" + x+y,
                         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         dataType: "json",
                         success: function (data) {
                             window.location.replace("Studentdataproject\Studentdataproject\Views\Home\Details.cshtml");
                             },
                         error: function (data) {
                             alert(data.responseText);
                         }
                 });
                     });   }
```

This is the script that I had in login view to call login in API controller. It is not calling the API controller.

API for login:

```
[HttpGet("Login/{email}/{password}")]
        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync(string email, string password)
        {
            obj1 = obj2.Login(email, password);
            if (obj1 == null)
            {
                return Ok(null);
            }
            else
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,obj1.email),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,obj1.roles)
                };
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                var princilple = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, princilple);

                return Ok();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Seems like you already know what to do. You can use ajax to call for your api directly.

Comment: @javachipper i had mentioned the script that i tried,  to call api from my html login page but its not working

Comment: Can you also post your web api, atleast the login function? That would help me determine if your url is correct or not.

Comment: @javachipper i mentioned it in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your URL in AJAX like this:

> url:  "https://localhost:44347/api/Values/Login/" + x + "/" + y,

Call web API with AJAX, which is similar to calling controller method.

Here is the CRUD operation of the `People` class with AJAX calling API. You can refer to it.

People Class:

```
 public class People
{ 
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Api:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class APICRUDController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MydbContext _context;

    public APICRUDController(MydbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    [HttpGet("GetPerson")]
    public IActionResult GetPerson(int? id)
    {
        var person = _context.People.ToList();
        if (id != null)
        {
            person = person.Where(x => x.id == id).ToList();
        }
        return Ok(person);
    }

    [HttpPost("AddPerson")]
    public IActionResult AddPerson([FromBody]People obj)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Ok("Please enter correct fields!");
        }
        _context.People.Add(obj);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Ok("Person added successfully!");
    }

    [HttpPost("UpdatePerson")]
    public IActionResult UpdatePerson([FromBody]People obj)
    {
        People people = (from c in _context.People
                         where c.id == obj.id
                         select c).FirstOrDefault();
        people.name = obj.name;
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPost("DeletePerson")]
    public void DeletePerson(int Id)
    {
        People people = (from c in _context.People
                             where c.id == Id
                             select c).FirstOrDefault();
        _context.People.Remove(people);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

View code:

```html
@model WebApplication_core.Models.People
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            loadData();
        })
        function loadData() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://localhost:44361/api/APICRUD/GetPerson',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    var html = '';
                    $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                        html += '<tr>';
                        html += '<td>' + item.id + '</td>';
                        html += '<td>' + item.name + '</td>';
                        html += '<td><a href="#" onclick="return Edit(' + item.id + ')">Edit</a> | <a href="#" onclick="Delete(' + item.id + ')">Delete</a></td>';
                        html += '</tr>';
                    });
                    $('.tbody').html(html);
                },
                error: function (errormessage) {
                    alert(errormessage.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
        function Add() {
            var obj = {
                name: $('#name').val(),
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'https://localhost:44361/api/APICRUD/AddPerson',
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.indexOf("successfully") > -1) {
                        loadData();
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        $('#name').val("");
                    }
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function (errormessage) {
                    alert(errormessage.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
        function Edit(Id) {
            $("#myModalLabel").text("Edit Person");
            $("#id").parent().show();
            $('#name').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://localhost:44361/api/APICRUD/GetPerson?id=' + Id,
                typr: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.length > 0) {
                        $('#id').val(result[0].id);
                        $('#name').val(result[0].name);
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');
                        $('#btnUpdate').show();
                        $('#btnAdd').hide();
                    }
                },
                error: function (errormessage) {
                    alert(errormessage.responseText);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
        function Update() {
            var obj = {
                id: parseInt($('#id').val()),
                name: $('#name').val(),
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://localhost:44361/api/APICRUD/UpdatePerson',
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: function () {
                    loadData();
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#id').val("");
                    $('#name').val("");
                },
                error: function (errormessage) {
                    alert(errormessage.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
        function Delete(Id) {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?")) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://localhost:44361/api/APICRUD/DeletePerson?Id=' + Id,
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                    success: function () {
                        alert("delete successfully!");
                        loadData();
                    },
                    error: function (errormessage) {
                        alert(errormessage.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        function HideKey() {
            $("#myModalLabel").text("Add Person");
            $("#id").parent().hide();
        }


    </script>
}


<div class="container">
    <h2>People Record</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="HideKey()">Add New User</button><br /><br />
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Action
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tbody"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="id"></label>
                        <input asp-for="id" class="form-control" disabled />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="name"></label>
                        <input asp-for="name" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" asp-validation-for="name"></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAdd" onclick="return Add();">Add</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnUpdate" style="display:none;" onclick="Update();">Update</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the result of this demo:

[image]

Comment: thank you ! now my login call to api is working fine